# web scraping - python/Jupyter/scrapy

Tags: python, json, jupyter, scrapy

Estoy tratando de aprender web scraping trabajando sobre esta página para comenzar:
http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html

Tengo que obtener en un dataframe una lista de los libros en esta página, con título y precio. Para eso primero estoy creando un JSON con el nombre del libro y el precio. Tengo esto, pero no controlo muy bien los selectores CSS y no me está guardando nada el JSON.

```python
class SimpleBookSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "simplebooks"
    start_urls = [
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html',
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.JsonWriterPipeline': 1},     
        'FILE_NAME': "quotes.jl"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        results = response.css('div.product_pod')
        for quote in results:
            yield{
                'title': product_pod.css('h3 a::attr(tittle)').extract_first(),
                'price': product_pod.css('div.product_price p.price_color::text').extract_first(),
            }
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código de tu araña tiene algunos errores:

- Aplicas el selector `response.css('div.product_pod')`, pero examinando el HTML de la página se ve que no son elementos tipo `div`, sino tipo `article` los que contienen la información buscada. Puedes poner `'article.product_pod'`, pero casi mejor puedes poner sólo el nombre de la clase `.product_pod`, sin especificar el tipo de elemento, y así te funcionará tanto si son `article` como si son `div`.

  Debido a este error no encuentra ningún elemento en la página y el bucle `for quote in results` no llega a ejecutarse.
- Ese bucle tenía un error, pues usas una variable llamada `product_pod`, que no está definida. Debería ser `quote`
- El selector para extraer el título tiene una errata, pues pusiste `tittle` con dos `t`.

Corrigiendo estos problemas te queda así:

```
import scrapy
import logging

class SimpleBookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "simplebooks"
    start_urls = [
        'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html',
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': logging.WARNING,
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {__name__ + ".JsonWriterPipeline": 1},
        'FILE_NAME': "quotes.jl"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        results = response.css('.product_pod')
        for quote in results:
            yield{
                'title': quote.css('h3 a::attr(title)').extract_first(),
                'price': quote.css('div.product_price p.price_color::text').extract_first().strip(),
            }
```

Completando el código con la clase `JsonWriterPipeline` que falta, y que puede ser la siguiente:

```
import json

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'w')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

he podido lanzar la araña y veo que en `items.jl` aparece la información deseada (el carácter `\u00a3` es el símbolo de la libra esterlina):

```json
{"title": "A Light in the Attic", "price": "\u00a351.77"}
{"title": "Tipping the Velvet", "price": "\u00a353.74"}
{"title": "Soumission", "price": "\u00a350.10"}
{"title": "Sharp Objects", "price": "\u00a347.82"}
{"title": "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind", "price": "\u00a354.23"}
{"title": "The Requiem Red", "price": "\u00a322.65"}
{"title": "The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job", "price": "\u00a333.34"}
{"title": "The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull", "price": "\u00a317.93"}
{"title": "The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics", "price": "\u00a322.60"}
{"title": "The Black Maria", "price": "\u00a352.15"}
{"title": "Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)", "price": "\u00a313.99"}
{"title": "Shakespeare's Sonnets", "price": "\u00a320.66"}
{"title": "Set Me Free", "price": "\u00a317.46"}
{"title": "Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)", "price": "\u00a352.29"}
{"title": "Rip it Up and Start Again", "price": "\u00a335.02"}
{"title": "Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991", "price": "\u00a357.25"}
{"title": "Olio", "price": "\u00a323.88"}
{"title": "Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849", "price": "\u00a337.59"}
{"title": "Libertarianism for Beginners", "price": "\u00a351.33"}
{"title": "It's Only the Himalayas", "price": "\u00a345.17"}
```